# Django - Postcode Issue

Tags: django-models

I am having issues with the postcode in my models.py file. I get the attached error. Can anybody help me?

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM4IS.png)

Models.py

```python
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils import timezone


# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', default='Upload Picture')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    eircode = models.CharField(max_length=7, default="V93CY93")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)

class KidProfile(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='kids')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to insert a null value into not null column named "postcode" in your table. postcode is not present in your "UserProfile" model class.

Comment: Thank you so much! Its working. We call postcode EIRCODE in Ireland.